# Formula for SUM on weeknumber and name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a formula that can sum a given persons onsite presence:
[image]

I tried following =SUMIFS(Onsite!A2:BM41;Onsite!A2:BM41;A2) but with no luck.

Comment: What output are looking for?

Comment: Example output and reasoning otherwise a lot of guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:M4,MATCH(A6,A2:A4,0),1):INDEX(B2:M4,MATCH(A6,A2:A4,0),COLUMNS(B:M)))
```

Assuming that you have the hours data in B2:M4, the names data in A2:A4 and the name you want to lookup in A6. You can modify the COLUMNS part with your first and last column of hours data.